# .desktop howto: persistent terminal, custom $HOME

Tags: 12.04, shortcuts

I have a web server .jar file (it's a jetty application) that I've created a .desktop file for. Clicking on the .desktop file opens a terminal, begins running the application, and then closes the terminal (and the application with it).

Two questions: first, how can I make this terminal persist? And secondly, the application needs to be launched from a particular directory, is there a way to specify that?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `Exec` line of your `.desktop` file as

`Exec=xterm -hold -e "cd <your desired directory>&&<command for your application startup here>"`.

This will spawn a `xterm` terminal emulator and hold it even after your application terminates until you explicitly close the `xterm` window.